# Open a RPM on a Mac?

Tags: rhel, rpm, osx

I am on a MacBook Pro running Apple Leopard (Mac OS X 10.5.8).

I would like to unpackage a RPM and view the files contained within the [wget-1.11.4-2.el5_4.1.src.rpm](http://ftp.redhat.com/pub/redhat/linux/enterprise/5Server/en/os/SRPMS/wget-1.11.4-2.el5_4.1.src.rpm) . I don't need to install the files to a particular location or run any %postinstall scripts or anything. I just want to unpackage this RPM so that I can view the source files underneath.

Is it possible to unpackage a RPM file on a non-RedHat/CentOS system?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

On modern systems, the built-in tar utility supports several other archive formats including rpm. So you can extract the files from the rpm with

```
tar -xf foo.rpm
```

Note that if you've installed GNU tools, `tar` may invoke GNU tar instead of the one that ships with macOS, depending on which set of GNU tools and on your `$PATH`. You need to use `/usr/bin/tar`, not GNU tar.

You can install rpm through [Darwin Ports](http://rpm.darwinports.com/) or [Fink](http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/rpm5) or [Mac Ports](http://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/rpm/Portfile) or even a [Darwin port, rpm4darwin](http://rpm4darwin.sourceforge.net/).

To extract files from an rpm package without installing it, you can use the companion utility `rpm2cpio`, e.g.

```
rpm2cpio foo.rpm | cpio -i -d
```

There's also a portable [`rpm2cpio`](http://www.redhat.com/archives/rpm-list/2003-June/msg00367.html) script if you don't want or can't get the version that's bundled with the `rpm` utility (the script may not work with older or newer versions of the rpm format though).

Comment: Seems like I want rpm2cpio, and I use Mac Ports, but unfortunately [rpm2cpio is not availalbe in macports](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=rpm2cpio). Maybe I'll try one of these alternatives.

Comment: @Stefan: Isn't the `rpm2cpio` utility in the `rpm` port? If not try the script.

Comment: @Giles : So it is, under `/opt/local/bin/rpm`! The PATH in my old environment must have been messed up.

Comment: It's also available in homebrew:
$ brew install rpm2cpio

Comment: Appears rpm2cpio is actually in the `rpm` brew these days...

Answer (score 29):

From the command line you can use the `tar` command. For example `tar -tf example.rpm | less` to list all of the files in the rpm.

Comment: can you give more details ?

Comment: @Archemar ```tar -tvzf some.rpm``` to list the contents ```tar -xvzf some.rpm``` to extract

Answer (score 10):

To unpack all the files to the local directory:

> tar -xvzf some.rpm

without the need to install any new tools

Answer (score 8):

Homebrew also has a recipe for rpm installation, just run

```
brew install rpm
```

Answer (score 4):

I would think that (like Windows and Linux) any archiver program should be able to decompress it. [iArchiver](http://iarchiver.com/), the [unArchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html), and [Archiver](http://archiverapp.com/) all list "read-only RPM" in their supported formats.

Comment: I guess most popular archivers for Windows - like WinRAR - have no such option.

Comment: From my perspective 'archiver' refers to single-purpose tools like `/usr/bin/tar`, `cpio`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, [Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) opens RPM files. I don't use it but [google list some links that might point at a GUI](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=unpack+rpm+file+Mac+OS+X).

Answer (score 2):

The portable rpm2cpio script is really good!