# how to run MySQL-devel-4.1.22-0.glibc23.x86_64.rpm file on mac?

Tags: osx, mysql, rpm

Is it possible to run MySQL-devel-4.1.22-0.glibc23.x86_64.rpm on my mac, and if so, how?

Comment: Unless the contents of that `.rpm` file are Mach-O binaries compiled for OS X, rather than the generally-expected ELF binaries compiled for Linux, running that `.rpm` is going to require virtualization of Linux.  Alternatively, you could compile from source or find a Mac version elsewhere

Answer (score 1):

You can install a RPM package on Mac via

```
brew install rpm
```

However, you need to check the RPM contains binaries for Mac. If it's a Linux RPM package (as used in RHEL), the programs won't work.

Related question: [Open a RPM on a Mac?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4664/open-a-rpm-on-a-mac)